# Replacing sed/tail/grep with awk only

Tags: linux, awk

I've below task to achieve. I completed it using awk/sed/tail/grep together but I believe it's doable using **only awk** - therefore I'm asking for your kind help:

What will be awk syntax for -

1. Get last line from file A (csv format)

`LAST=$(tail -n1 A)`

2. Check if line from file A exist in file B (csv as well), if yes...

`NO=$(grep -nw "$LAST" B|awk -F: {print $1})'`

3. Check if there are newer lines in file B, if yes...

```
BELOW=$(expr $NO + 1)
if awk "NR==$BELOW" B; then
```

4. Delete everything in file B from $NO to the 2nd row

`sed -i "2,$NO d" B; fi`

BIG THANKS for any help - appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO, good that you have shown us your code, very good. Could you please post samples of your inputs and expected output in your question and let us know then?

Comment: What if _line from file A [does not] exist in file B_ or there are no _newer lines in B_? So please, post sample files and expected output in all cases (found in B, not found in B, no newer lines in B). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
awk 'FNR == NR { last = $0; next }
     !newer && $0 == last { newer = 1; next }
     newer || FNR == 1' A B
```

Basically `FNR == NR { last = $0; next }` sets `last` to to each line as long as we are in the first file, so in the end it will be the first file's last line.

In the second file if we are not in the newer lines and the line equals `last`, the next line is newer than what was in the first file: `!newer && $0 == last { newer = 1; next }`.

And when we are either in the first line or the newer lines of the second file, it is printed: `newer || FNR == 1`.

This differs from the original in that it prints out the newer lines of B, instead of modifying B in place. Of course you can redirect the output to a temporary file in the shell and then move it over B if it contains more than one line. Or have Awk return an exit status and use that, e.g.,:

```
tmpf=`mktemp B'.XXXXXX'`
awk 'FNR == NR { last = $0; next }
!newer && $0 == last { newer = NR; next }
newer || FNR == 1 { print }
END { exit (!newer || NR == newer) }' \
A B >"$tmpf" && mv "$tmpf" B || rm -f "$tmpf"
```

Admittedly not entirely in Awk anymore, but I'd say close enough and better in practice.